# Query optimization in MySQL

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql

At first, i have to say that this topic is very common topic. I have studied all related topics but i can not find out the answer. 
I have three tables. Messages table has 300.000, tags table has 1 million and message_tag table has about 10 million rows. message_tag.message_id and message_tag.tag_id columns have indexes.  My purpose is select messages which linked a spesified tag. However query times are too long. There is not any query time shorter than 20 seconds. On the other hand sometimes query does not give even a result due to long query times. Table structures and my query are below. How can i handle this problem? I am open all suggestions. Even i can recreate tables with a new schema. Database is MySql, Storage motor is MyIsam. .

```
table name: messages
columns :
id (int)
message (vharchar)
message_poster (vharchar)

table name: tags
id (int)
tag (vharchar)

table name : message_tag
columns :
message_id (int)
tag_id (int)
```

My query:

```
SELECT                    messages.message_poster,
                          messages.message
                     FROM tags, messages, message_tag 
                     WHERE message_tag.tag_id=191
                     AND messages.id= message_tag.message_id
```

Comment: You have read all related topics, but did you find anything about an "index" in there? If you could tell us what indexes (indices?) you have, please do so. If you can't, find out what they are, and how to apply them :D

Comment: Please provide the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE messages`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE tags`, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE message_tag`

Comment: How are you using the `tags` table?  It's in your from list, but not in your `select` or `where` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And here is an example of why I don't like using `,` notation.

You don't relate `message_tag` to `tags`.  Instead, you join *EVERY* message tag to every other row.

This is what you have...

```
SELECT
  messages.message_poster,
  messages.message
FROM
  messages
INNER JOIN
  message_tag
    ON messages.id= message_tag.message_id
CROSS JOIN
  tags
WHERE
  message_tag.tag_id=191
```

This is what you ***should*** have...

```
SELECT
  messages.message_poster,
  messages.message
FROM
  messages
INNER JOIN
  message_tag
    ON messages.id = message_tag.message_id
INNER JOIN
  tags
    ON tags.id     = message_tag.tag_id
WHERE
  message_tag.tag_id = 191
```

*(Or, just don't JOIN on `tags` at all, you're not using it in this case.  Though I appreciate that this may be a simplified version of the actual query.)*

It's much harder to mess that up with `ANSI-92` notation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a two-dimensional index on message_tag (over both fields), and rewrite the WHERE to

```
WHERE 
    message_tag.tag_id=191 AND 
    message_tag.message_id = messages.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a join condition between 2 tables, maybe `tags` and `message_tag` ?